# Check if a UITableViewCell is completely visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewport, uitableview

How can I check if a UITableViewCell is completely visible on the screen (not cut off by the tab or nav bar)?

I can get the visible cells with this code:

```
NSArray *indexes = [_tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
```

but I want to exclude cells that are not entirely visible in the screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have, get the visible cells. The only ones that might be partial are the top and bottom ones. For each, check if its rect (`rectForRowAtIndexPath:`) is fully within the bounds of the table view (based on `contentSize` and `contentOffset`, using `CGRectContainsRect`).