# List down Videos in UITableview like Vine app and autoplay them in UiTableview like Vine app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I get video links from Web-Service API , now what i want is that those videos should be display in `UITableview` like vine app and they must be autoplay in `UITableview` itself like vine app.

I have taken custom `UITableview` cell , in which i am adding `MPMoviePlayercontroller`,but the things are not working.

Comment: What's not working exactly?

Comment: check out nagem's answer, i have done those things  ,but those things are not working correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of these three answers to achieve what you're looking for:

First, implement UIScrollViewDelegate to know when the tableview has stopped scrolling:
[how to check when UITableView is done scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521681/how-to-check-when-uitableview-is-done-scrolling)

Next, Figure out which cells are completely on screen using `indexPathForVisibleRows` as well as checking the rect of the cell:
[Check if a UITableViewCell is completely visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309364/check-if-a-uitableviewcell-is-completely-visible)

Finally, play all `MPMoviePlayercontroller` views, assuring they are the right size with:
[iPhone SDK:How do you play video inside a view? Rather than fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266750/iphone-sdkhow-do-you-play-video-inside-a-view-rather-than-fullscreen)

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more descriptive of what isn't working, unfortunately. Do you know where in the process it is failing? Is indexPathForVisibleRows returning the right indexes? Are you able to access the correct MPMoviePlayerControl object?